# Can Jest and Sinon.JS test incremental getData from the server (in the case of React and Redux)?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, sinon

If the way that Jest tests action and reducer is

```
let getDataThunk = actions.getData(0, 999);   // getting data 0 to 999
requests.push(store.dispatch(getDataThunk));
```

Normally it would work fine.

However, because the testing code would do

```
Promise.all(requests).then(() => {
    const theActions = store.getActions();
```

And then, `theActions` is checked to make sure all the proper ones are there.  However, we cannot really get all the actions, because at this point it is only after the first request is resolved.  There can be 1 or more request that would go get more data (because it is incremental).  In this case, can Jest and Sinon.JS handle this test case?

(the non-testing code does the incremental getData this way: in the `then` handler of the first batch of data returns, do another `dispatch()` to get the second batch of data, and so on, until all data is obtained).

If Jest and Sinon may not be suited to do it, we may have to mock up that second `dispatch()` also by Jest's

```
let getDataIncrementalThunk = actions.getData(1000, 1999);
requests.push(store.dispatch(getDataIncrementalThunk));
```

and do the testing. It may not be ideal because we have to mock up this second `dispatch()`, instead of letting the non-testing code to do it, but we can still test the other parts of the code and still have some test coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found one solution, although it may not be the best solution, but it is one solution:

1. When my non-testing code does the `dispatch()`, one additional request is made to the server.  Therefore, there is an additional request in `server.requests`
2. So I can just again, do a `Promise.all(server.requests)` on all requests (or only for this second request alone), and do the `then()` handler for it.
3. For this second request, send some mocked up data to it.
4. In the `then` handler, verify the expected behavior, such as the action type being the expected one, and that the final state contains data from both fetches, which for example, could be the result of the two arrays concatenated.